# Automating Clicks inside Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a very simple page with an Iframe of a different web page inside it.
The main page looks like this:

```
<button type="button" id="btnStart">
  Start Simulation
</button>

<div class="3rdparty">
  <iframe src="http://somewhere.com" height="400" width="400" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
</div>
```

And assuming that this is the main content of the webpage inside the iframe:

```
<form>
  <select name="level">
    <option val=1>One</option>
    <option val=2>Two</option>
    <option val=3>Three</option>
    <option val=4>Four</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Go</submit>
</form>
```

Is it possible with jquery on the main page to select 'One' then click Go and after 3 sec, select Two then Go and then 3 sec, select Three then Go. Each page when Go is click has the same form elements so clicking through each select option should be doable? If so, how can I do it? I hope you understand my question if you need more details please comment.

Comment: You should really look into [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) if you want browser automation.

Comment: @Liam I would love to but my time to do this task is really limited and wondering if I could use what I already started studying which is jquery

Comment: Standard browsers won't allow you to do this, as it would be a great security issue.

Comment: @DarthJDG I see so its not possible. Okay thank you!